# Not able to import 'Intertools' in python

Tags: python

I am not able to install 'Intertools' in python. Following are the errors

When used Pip install Method in Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\avira>pip install intertools
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\avira\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\avira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install intertools'
```

When used Pip install Method in Anaconda Prompt:

```
(base) C:\Users\avira>pip install intertools
Collecting intertools
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement intertools (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for intertools
```

Please help me how to install 'Intertools' library in python.

Comment: did you mean `itertools`?

Comment: I think you have a typo....try Itertools and not intertools

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realized my mistake. I was trying to install 'intertools' instead of 'itertools'. U saved my hours.

Answer (score 1):

"Intertools" ?

Are you sure you are not trying to use 'itertools' instead ? Which is built-in in Python. Just import it and that's it.